# OpenCover.Console test fails when code reads data from config file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, opencover

I have this strange problem. When I use the OpenCover from Visual Studio all tests pass and everything seems fine.

Image from Visual Studio here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/awmWy.png

But when I want to automate the tests using the OpenCover.Console.exe than some tests fail. I have noticed that the 2 failing tests read from config file.

Either the test or the code that is tested reads from config file using *ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someConfigValue"]*.
I have the same values in the main project and the test project *appsettings*.

The two failing tests when executing from console image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a77Tt.png

In addition I provide the command used for OpenCover.Console.exe.

> "OpenCover.Console.exe" 
>   -register 
>   -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" 
>   -targetargs:"/noisolation /testcontainer:\"E:\TEAM\TestProject.Tests\bin\Debug\TestProject.Tests.dll" /resultsfile:TestResults.trx" 
>   -mergebyhash 
>   -output:CodeCoverage.xml

## **UPDATE [*04 September 2015*]**

Since I did not find any particular solution, I came up with a workaround.
Practically I have taken as granted that configuration file and all its data does not belong to unit tests, but to integration tests.

So in my code I do not use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someConfigValue"] any more. What I did is created a ConfigurationService and in the IConfigurationService I have all the methods I need for getting the values from the config file.

Having this injected in the BL of the solution, I use Mocks for unit testing purposes.

Comment: Is the Current Working Directory when running from the console the same as when running from Visual Studio?

Comment: I suppose no, but will accept your suggestion and try it.

Comment: Nope, still no good. Visual Studio uses ***-target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"***

Comment: try `-targetdir:"E:\TEAM\TestProject.Tests\bin\Debug"` this should cause OpenCover to set it's `CurrentDirectory` to that location; you could then try  removing the path from the `/testcontainer` argument passed to mstest (vstest.console.exe)

Comment: Thank you @ShaunWilde, I will try your suggestion. Even though I ended up with another workaround.

Comment: please update your question or even answer you your own question with your workaround as others may find it useful.

Comment: @ShaunWilde I just tried your suggestion and the same thing happens again. I will write down my workaround as an UPDATE to the question